# Select all used values of a specific field as source for dialog list choices

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In my Lotus Notes Database, I want to fill the choices available in a dialog list based on the previously entered values for this field.

I set type of the field to "Dialog list", chose "Use formula for choices" and selected "Allow values not in list".

However, I don't know what to enter as a formula:
The formula's result should be all values for the field `Foo` specified in the database.

I tried the following formula which results in an empty list, however:

```
@Unique(SELECT Foo)
```

There are definitely documents with values for `Foo` in the database.

Which formula can I use?
Or do you know better solutions to my problem than using a formula?

Many thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a view with at least a column that displays the Foo field. You can then use @DbColumn in your formula to retrieve all values from e.g. column 1 containing the Foo field:

```
@Unique(@DbColumn("";"":"database.nsf";"Your new view";1))
```

Here is more informatiom about @DbColumn: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_GENERATING_CHOICES_FOR_LISTS_STEPS.html

Comment: The problem with the second solution is that I can't enable "Allow values not in list" then, can I?

Comment: Ok - this way it works fine. The "database.nsf" parameter is even optional; I could simply specify "". Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Similar way, but error handling included.

```
Look := @DbColumn("":""; ""; "$LookFoo"; 1);
@If(@IsError(Look); ""; @Unique(Look))
```

Database parameter can be empty, if you are reading from the current. If there is a problem with cache, you can make first parameter like - @DbColumn("":"NoCache";...
Hope it helps.

Comment: It is debatable whether silent-fail (in this case: empty list instead of error message in the list) are the better way of handling errors ;-)

Comment: OK, silent case or case, when user selects "A view of that name cannot be found in the specified database" value. :-)